# 'Ridge' is not a CV regularization model; try ManualAlphaSelection instead

Tags: yellowbrick

I am trying to find the best Alpha for a Ridge model without CV, using Yellowbrick ManualAlphaSelection API.  My code is pretty basic and it has been taken from the yellowbrick´s documentation. Even though it does not work:

```
from yellowbrick.regressor import ManualAlphaSelection
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
model = ManualAlphaSelection(Ridge(),  scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.show()
```

Python  raises the message: 'Ridge' is not a CV regularization model; try ManualAlphaSelection instead.
But this message is wrong because the  ManualAlphaSelection is already being used.

Answer (score 2):

This actually appears to be a bug in our library 
Would you mind [opening up a bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/issues/new?template=bug_report.md) so we can be sure to fix it? Thank you for checking out Yellowbrick!

Comment: Update: we just merged the fix! https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/pull/1067

Comment: I am still getting that same error four months later.

Comment: Hi @CRich we just did a release on October 9; try updating your yellowbrick installation with `pip install -U yellowbrick` and check out the updated documentation here: https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/alphas.html. Thanks for using Yellowbrick!